# jQuery AJAX post data is null in c# web api controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I am sending data to a `c# web api controller` by using the following call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "menuApi/menu/Cost",
    data: JSON.stringify(order),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) { window.alert('done')},
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

The `c# controller` on server side is like this:

```
public string Cost([FromBody] string order)
{
    var sOrder = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(order);

    return "";
}
```

The order object in Javascript is a complex object with nested arrays and properties. I am getting data as null. I am not sure how can I get the order sent through the ajax call.

Edit: This is my order object

```
var order = {
    name:"",
    id:"",
    cost:"",
    details: {
        sItem:[{name:"",cost:""}], 
        dItem:[{name:"",cost:"", components:[{name:"",quantity:""}]}]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show definition of `order`

Comment: Try to use : `application/json; charset=utf-8`

Comment: Try using a object as a parameter for your action rather then a string. MVC's mapping functionality should do its thing

Comment: Its not an mvc application. I have just added web api in simple asp.net project

Comment: @MichalHainc tried that but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it, you need to post the ajax request as form data with empty parameter/form field name like this:

```
    var order = {
        name: "",
        id: "",
        cost: "",
        details: {
            sItem: [{ name: "", cost: "" }],
            dItem: [{ name: "", cost: "", components: [{ name: "", quantity: "" }] }]
        }
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "api/Values",
        data: {'': JSON.stringify(order)} ,
        success: function (data) { window.alert('done') },            
    });
```

Comment: Its not working for me. The only problem, I am facing is that when actual object, which is a complex nested array object, the data I get is null. Even I tried your example with 
orderStr = "Hello";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "menuApi/menu/Cost",       
        data: { '': orderStr },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) { window.alert('done')},
    });

Comment: Ok let me try 1:1

Comment: Yes got it, I didn't pay attention to the contentType. Yes it is working now

Comment: this is wonderful. Could not think of trying it with empty parameter. Still dont know the mechanics of why it is working now, but it is working.

Answer (score 0):

The model binder's already done it for you, no need for deserializing. You just need to change parameter type to `object` or `dynamic`. Thing left is consideration to remove that redundant processing:

```
    public string Cost([FromBody] object order)
    {
        var sOrder = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(order.ToString());

        return "";
    }
```

Comment: There is nothing being done automatic here. It is not MVC project. I have added a web api and calling it from the ajax call.